# Node.js "on" function - What does it do?

Tags: node.js, function

```
 var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(file),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
```

And is any way how to make "on" working synchronous. Code inside "on" loop need to be done before executing loop again. Is any way how to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying with your last sentence. Events are always asynchronously.

Comment: what do you mean by working synchronous? The on event will be fired when a line event is emitted, isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the `on` function registers an event handler for a specific event.

The [`readline::line`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line) event serves for this purpose:

> Emitted whenever the input stream receives a \n, usually received when
>   the user hits enter, or return. This is a good hook to listen for user
>   input.
>   
>   — [NodeJS documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line)

By the way, which keywords did you use for your search? I used `nodejs readline.createInterface` and the first result was this NodeJS documentation page!

Comment: I was looking for node.js on function and simullar.
Thanks. Helped a lot

Comment: @user2316602 Searching for `nodejs on function` yields again the Node.js documentation page: [Events Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_event_listener).